# Namespace with multiple files

Tags: c++, namespaces

Inside FileThree.h

```
#ifndef FILETHREE
#define FILETHREE
namespace blue{}
class Filethree
{
public:
    Filethree(void);
    ~Filethree(void);
};
#endif
```

Inside FileThree.cpp

```
#include "Filethree.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
namespace blue{
     void blueprint(int nVar){
         cout<<"red::"<<nVar<<endl;
     }
}
Filethree::Filethree(void)
{
}

Filethree::~Filethree(void)
{
}
```

Inside FileFour.h

```
#ifndef FILEFOUR
#define FILEFOUR
namespace red{}
class FileFour
{
public:
    FileFour(void);
    ~FileFour(void);
};
#endif
```

Inside FileFour.cpp

```
#include "FileFour.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
 namespace red{
     void redprint(double nVar){
         cout<<"red::"<<nVar<<endl;
     }
}
FileFour::FileFour(void)
{
}

FileFour::~FileFour(void)
{
}
```

Inside main.cpp

```
#include "FileFour.h"
 #include "Filethree.h"
using namespace red ;
using namespace blue ;

int main()
{
    blueprint(12);
return 0;
}
```

When i compile the above file it gives me the following error .

```
 error C3861: 'blueprint': identifier not found
```

Can anyone tell me why i am getting this error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiler can't find functions when they are not declared in header files.
You need to declare `blueprint` function in `namespace blue` in FileThree.h

FileThree.h:

```
namespace blue{
    void blueprint(int nVar);
}
```

Same to `redprint` function, need to declare it in FileFour.h inside `namespace red`

FileFour.h

```
namespace red{
   void redprint(double nVar);
}
```

Comment: But i have declared the same inside cpp file ..and given a forward declaration inside header file . Am i missing something ?

Comment: you are missing what I said. :) definition in .cpp files are seen at link time.

Comment: So only header file compiles and during linking they link with cpp files to get the definition .Please correct if i am wrong .

Comment: Where you call `blueprint` in `main`, the compiler has to have seen the name `blueprint` before being able to use it. This can come from a declaration or a definition of the function. In any program you can have as many re-declarations of functions as you like, but only ever one definition. This is why we split our code up into `.h` and `.cpp` files. We keep our declarations in headers (on the whole), and our definitions in cpp files. The compiler compiles cpp files, but pulls in header files in order to see the declarations of functions.

Comment: @PeterWood::Thanks for make my understanding little bit clear on the compilation and linking process .

Answer (score 1):

> When you separate your code into multiple files, you’ll have to use a
>   namespace in the header and source file.

```
add.h

#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

namespace basicMath
{
    // function add() is part of namespace basicMath
    int add(int x, int y);
}

#endif
add.cpp


#include "add.h"

namespace basicMath
{
    // define the function add()
    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
main.cpp


#include "add.h" // for basicMath::add()

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << basicMath::add(4, 3) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

source : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/user-defined-namespaces/comment-page-4/#comment-464049

Answer (score 0):

Inside FileFour.h

```
#ifndef FILEFOUR
#define FILEFOUR
namespace red{
     void redprint(int nVar);        
}
class FileFour
{
public:
    FileFour(void);
    ~FileFour(void);
};
#endif
```

Inside FileFour.cpp

```
#include "FileFour.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
void red::redprint(int nVar)
{
    cout<<"red"<<nVar<<endl;
}
FileFour::FileFour(void)
{
}

FileFour::~FileFour(void)
{
}
```

Inside Filethree.h

```
#ifndef FILETHREE
#define FILETHREE
namespace blue{
     void blueprint(int nVar);       
}
class Filethree
{
public:
    Filethree(void);
    ~Filethree(void);
};
#endif
```

Inside Filethree.cpp

```
#include "Filethree.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
void blue::blueprint(int nVar)
{
    cout<<"blue"<<nVar<<endl;
}
Filethree::Filethree(void)
{
}

Filethree::~Filethree(void)
{
}
```

Inside main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "FileFour.h"
 #include "Filethree.h"
using namespace blue ;
int main()
{
    blueprint(12);
return 0;
}
```

Definition shall be inside cpp files where as declaration in header files.

Comment: remove 'extern' in FileThree.h and FileFour.h

Comment: After removing extern too , it will not give any error .Please see my edited post .
Anyway thanks for giving the link , which helps me to understand the compilation and linking process .